# Is there a common name for the scale [0 2 4 5 7 8 10] (C D E F G Ab Bb C)?

Tags: theory, scales, modes

Is there a standard or common way to refer to the scale with pitch classes 024578T or C-D-E-F-G-Ab-Bb-C (on C)?

There's many ways to refer to it as a mixture of another scale. Like saying "natural minor with raised 3rd" or, major with b6 and b7. But I'm wondering if it also has a name of its own that is in (semi)common use.

Comment: No, but this does: https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/27468/is-there-a-name-for-a-minor-scale-with-a-raised-3rd-or-a-major-scale-with-a-lowe

I'll close the question.

Answer (score -1):

Make your choice, depending on the root note you want:
[image]